# Launch business-objects querys from Excel with dynamic data

Tags: vba, excel, business-objects

I need to launch everyday a business object report modifying a list of phone numbers in a dimension called "Phone". I would like to have an Excel file where I set the phone numbers I would like to look for in the BO universe, launch the report and save the results. I have modified an example I found, but I don't know how to modify the conditions with VBA code of the report. If I just want to refresh the report, it works fine, but never adds or updates de value of the condition. Any idea?

In my Excel I have info in cells which I pass as variable to the VBA function:

```
C2 = Business Object login
C3 = Business Object password
C4 = BO report path
C5 = Exported results path
C6 = list of phone numbers separated with "," o ";" (whatever is needed)
```

The VBA code I run from Excel:

```
Sub Exec_BO_Query()
    Dim BoApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set BoApp = CreateObject("BusinessObjects.application")
    With BoApp
        .Visible = True
        .LoginAs Worksheets("Configuration").Range("C2").Value, Worksheets("Configuration").Range("C3").Value, False
        .Documents.Open (Worksheets("Configuration").Range("C4").Value)
             With .ActiveDocument
                  .Queries.Item(1).Conditions.Add "Phone number", "Phone", "In list", Worksheets("Configuration").Range("C6").Value 
                  .Refresh
                  .SaveAs Worksheets("Configuration").Range("C5").Value
                  .Close
            End With
        .Application.Quit
    End With
    Set BoApp = Nothing
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
End Sub
```

I don't know how to use properly the conditions (even I don't know if is the right object to use). The syntax according to the documentation is this one:

```
var.Add(class, objectorcondition, [operator], [operand1], [operand1type], [operand2], [operand2type])

var is the name of the Conditions variable that you declare.
class is a string that identifies the class.
objectorcondition is a string that identifies the condition.
operator identifies the operation. This parameter is optional.
operand1, operand2 are each operands for the condition. These parameters are optional.
operand1type, operand2type are each operand types for the corresponding operator. These parameters are optional.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Juagar - I do not know business-objects that well, but it definitely looks like your `Conditions.Add` line is missing some commas.

Comment: You are right, in the example the commas are missing, but in my code, are written and doesn't work well (the code runs and refresh de report, but doesn't add the condition to the report). I'm going to correct the mistake in the question, thanks!
Here is the real code I have:

.Queries.Item(1).Conditions.Add "Información de la orden", "ID Orden", "In list", "90388590"

Comment: Do you need to do this from within Excel? How many phone numbers to you usually have? What is the maximum number of phone numbers?